# Single Email Limitaion

Tags: apex, email, limits

When I am using the contact Id at the time of sending email it as counted as limit . What are the perameters we need to take so that single email method will not count as lmit for contacts .

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage  email1 = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
email1.setSubject('SUB'); 
list<string> s=new list<string>();                       
email1.setTargetObjectId([
    select id,email from contact where email='test@abc.com' limit 1
].id);//add account email id
email1.setPlainTextBody('TEXT2');
//email1.setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient(treatAsRecipient);
```

Comment: When you use Apex Code to email a Lead Id, Contact Id, or an arbitrary address, it will always count towards the daily mass email limits. There is no way to bypass this rule.

Answer (score 3):

This limit seems clearly covered in [Email Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_email.htm) from the `Salesforce Developer Limits Quick Reference`:

> ## [Email Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_email.htm)
>
> Using the API or Apex, you can send single emails to a maximum of 5,000 external email addresses per day based on Greenwich Mean Time (GMT). Single emails sent using the email author or composer in Salesforce don't count toward this limit. There’s no limit on sending individual emails to contacts, leads, person accounts, and users in your org directly from account, contact, lead, opportunity, case, campaign, or custom object pages.
>
> When sending single emails, keep in mind:
>
> - You can specify up to 100 recipients for the To field and up to 25 recipients for the CC and BCC fields in each SingleEmailMessage.
> - If you use SingleEmailMessage to email your org’s internal users, specifying the user’s ID in setTargetObjectId means the email doesn’t count toward the daily limit. However, specifying internal users’ email addresses in setToAddresses means the email does count toward the limit.

A couple notes:

- This section only applies when called from *"custom object pages"*:

  > There’s no limit on sending individual emails to contacts, leads, person accounts, and users in your org directly from account, contact, lead, opportunity, case, campaign, or custom object pages.
- This section only mentions **`User`** records as being exempt:

  > If you use SingleEmailMessage to email your org’s internal users, specifying the user’s ID in setTargetObjectId means the email doesn’t count toward the daily limit. However, specifying internal users’ email addresses in setToAddresses means the email does count toward the limit.

Comment: Single emails sent using the email author or composer in Salesforce don't count toward this limit. There’s no limit on sending individual emails to contacts, leads, person accounts, and users in org directly from account. These lines show that if send emails to contact id it should not count as limit , but it is counting as limit when I am using the code as above , do you any example for the way to sen emails to contacts so that it should not be count as limit ?

Comment: @lushmav Did you even read my note on that snippet? That only applies when composing an email from the custom object page. When using `setTargetObjectId`, ***only the*** `User` ***object is exempt***.

Comment: Every day night we are running 8 batches , to send emails to conacts . Is there any way that we can send more than 10k emails dialy ?

Comment: Not via Salesforce, not staying within the standard limits. You can talk to your sales rep or investigate the [many apps](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/category/mass-emails) in this space.

Comment: ok, thank you very much.  We will design jobs to send emails through talend. insted of going for apps , which will be good ?