# i want to send single email to a user when batch scope size is greater than 3000

Tags: batch, scheduled-apex

In my code i fetch a list of task which i want to send to user in a single mail but max batch scope size is 2000. so in my case, if record is exceeded from 2000 means 2010 or 2011 then user got 2 mails. thts i dont want. i want user got single mail with 2010 record.

here is my code.

```
global class PendingTaskBatch1 implements Database.Batchable<Sobject>{
    Map<String,List<Task>> listOfTask=new Map<String,List<Task>>();
    global Database.QueryLocator Start(Database.BatchableContext bc)
    {

        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT ID,createddate,what.id,Owner.Email,OwnerId,Owner.Name,Status,ActivityDate,Subject from Task WHERE Status != 'Completed' AND Owner.isactive = True  AND ActivityDate!=NULL AND ActivityDate <=:system.today()]);
    }

    global void Execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Task>scope)
    {
        for(Task task:scope)
        {
            if(!listOfTask.containsKey(task.Owner.Email))
            {
                listOfTask.put(task.Owner.Email, new List<Task>());
            }
            listOfTask.get(task.Owner.Email).add(task);
        }

        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> pendingTaskEmailAlert = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

        for(String mail :listOfTask.keySet())
        {
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            String[] toAddresses = new String[] {mail};
                email.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
            email.setSubject('Details of task due by Today');
            String userName=listOfTask.get(mail)[0].Owner.Name;
            String htmlBody= '';

            htmlBody = '<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" align="center" bgcolor="#F7F7F7">'+
                +'<tr>'+
                +'<td style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; font-family:Calibri;line-height: 20px; color: #333;"><br />'+
                +'<br />'+
                +'Dear, '+username+',</td>'+
                +'</tr>'+
                +'<tr>'+
                +'<td style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; font-family:Calibri; line-height: 18px; color: #333;">You have Pending Task</td>'+
                +'</tr>'+
                +'</table>';

            htmlBody +=  '<table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse"><tr><th>Related To</th><th>Subject</th><th>Created Date</th><th> Due Date</th></tr>';

            for(Task task:listOfTask.get(mail))
            {
                String dueDate = task.ActivityDate.format();
                String Subject =task.Subject;
                DateTime dt=task.CreatedDate;
                String what=task.What.Id;
                String status=task.Status;
                htmlBody +='<tr><td>' + what + '</td><td>' + Subject +'</td><td>'+ dt + '</td><td>'+ dueDate +'</td><td>'+ status + '</td></tr>';
            }
            htmlBody += '</table><br>';
            email.setHtmlBody(htmlBody);
            pendingTaskEmailAlert.add(email);
        }
        Messaging.sendEmail(pendingTaskEmailAlert);

    }
    global void Finish(Database.BatchableContext bc)
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you want a single email to be sent even if number of tasks exceed 2000?

Comment: yes pranay .............

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be to implement the Database.Stateful interface, and then compile the email in the batch's Finish method instead of in the execute method.

Check out 'Using State in Batch Apex' in [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm#apex_batch_maintain_state).

Here is a relevant quote from it:

> Each execution of a batch Apex job is considered a discrete
>   transaction. For example, a batch Apex job that contains 1,000 records
>   and is executed without the optional scope parameter is considered
>   five transactions of 200 records each.
>
> If you specify Database.Stateful in the class definition, you can
>   maintain state across these transactions. When using
>   Database.Stateful, only instance member variables retain their values
>   between transactions. Static member variables don’t retain their
>   values and are reset between transactions. Maintaining state is useful
>   for counting or summarizing records as they’re processed. For example,
>   suppose your job processed opportunity records. You could define a
>   method in execute to aggregate totals of the opportunity amounts as
>   they were processed.
>
> If you don’t specify Database.Stateful, all static and instance member
>   variables are set back to their original values.

However, if you go this route know that it will impact the performance of your batch and if you have a large number of tasks or task owners then you could hit system limits:

1. the heap size limit from the task map that you are using to store
       the email to tasks mapping.
2. Too many emails sent in a single sendEmail call or too many emails in
       one day. You are limited to 5000 emails in a day, you can get around
       that by using `email.setTargetObjectId` instead of
       `email.setToAddresses`, [see here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000002490&language=en_US&type=1). You are also limited to
       sending 100 emails at once with a single call to
       Messaging.sendEmail, so you will need to loop through it. But you
       can also only call Messaging.sendEmail 10 times in the same
       transaction, so you will be limited to sending 1000 email messages
       within a single run of the batch.

If these restrictions are okay, then you should be able to use Database.Stateful.

EDIT: For example, modifying your code slightly to do a very simple version of this might look like the following. NOTE: this code would need to be updated to mitigate the risk of hitting the limits mentioned above, for example by splitting up the list of emails into chunks of 100 to avoid sending too many at once.

```
global class PendingTaskBatch1 implements Database.Batchable<Sobject>,
                                          Database.Stateful {

    Map<String,List<Task>> listOfTask=new Map<String,List<Task>>();

    global Database.QueryLocator Start(Database.BatchableContext bc)
    {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT ID,createddate,what.id,Owner.Email,OwnerId,Owner.Name,Status,ActivityDate,Subject from Task WHERE Status != 'Completed' AND Owner.isactive = True  AND ActivityDate!=NULL AND ActivityDate <=:system.today()]);
    }

    global void Execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Task>scope)
    {
        for(Task task:scope)
        {
            if(!listOfTask.containsKey(task.Owner.Email))
            {
                listOfTask.put(task.Owner.Email, new List<Task>());
            }
            listOfTask.get(task.Owner.Email).add(task);
        }
    }
    global void Finish(Database.BatchableContext bc)
    {
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> pendingTaskEmailAlert = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

        for(String mail :listOfTask.keySet())
        {
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            String[] toAddresses = new String[] {mail};
                email.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
            email.setSubject('Details of task due by Today');
            String userName=listOfTask.get(mail)[0].Owner.Name;
            String htmlBody= '';

            htmlBody = '<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" align="center" bgcolor="#F7F7F7">'+
                +'<tr>'+
                +'<td style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; font-family:Calibri;line-height: 20px; color: #333;"><br />'+
                +'<br />'+
                +'Dear, '+username+',</td>'+
                +'</tr>'+
                +'<tr>'+
                +'<td style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; font-family:Calibri; line-height: 18px; color: #333;">You have Pending Task</td>'+
                +'</tr>'+
                +'</table>';

            htmlBody +=  '<table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse"><tr><th>Related To</th><th>Subject</th><th>Created Date</th><th> Due Date</th></tr>';

            for(Task task:listOfTask.get(mail))
            {
                String dueDate = task.ActivityDate.format();
                String Subject =task.Subject;
                DateTime dt=task.CreatedDate;
                String what=task.What.Id;
                String status=task.Status;
                htmlBody +='<tr><td>' + what + '</td><td>' + Subject +'</td><td>'+ dt + '</td><td>'+ dueDate +'</td><td>'+ status + '</td></tr>';
            }
            htmlBody += '</table><br>';
            email.setHtmlBody(htmlBody);
            pendingTaskEmailAlert.add(email);
        }
        Messaging.sendEmail(pendingTaskEmailAlert);
    }

}
```

Comment: If u give some example then its easy to me to understand

Comment: @Radhe I edited my answer to add a basic example using your code. I do not recommend using this directly as it is not as robust as it should be.

Comment: thnxx for the example...its help me..

Answer (score 2):

Before I begin with the answer I would like to add few points.

1. Total number of sendEmail methods allowed is 10. Thus in a batch you cannot send more than 10 emails in start,finish and execute.

So if task records have more than 10 owners then the solution suggested by Kyle with fail.

2. You are sending email to user and As I can see you are using `setTooAddress` in email. We have a limit of 5000 emails a day. if you use `setTargetObjectId` as userID you will be able to send unlimited emails to the user(Given 10 emails per transaction still apply)

Finally,

3. You have to create your logic in such a way that your start, execute and finish methods can save state and use later. This can be done by using `Database.stateful`

Thus logic  goes like

- Implement Database.Stateful in your Batch and create a map of OwnerId vs his tasks's in html format.
- In Execute method create populate the Map with the html task content in table format. As map is declared as global its value will persists in start, finish and execute.
- In execute method call a Secondary `EmailSenderBatch` batch and pass it the Map you have created in `PendingTaskBatch1` . The secondary batches also implements Database.Stateful and has scope of 10. 10 cause we can send at max 10 emails in a transaction. The object your Email batch works on is user to whom we have to send email
- In your execute method of the secondary batch, use `setTargetObjectId` (Hack for unlimited free emails)

  Thus your code will be like.

  ```
  global class PendingTaskBatch1 implements Database.Batchable<Sobject>, Database.Stateful{


  Map<String,String> ownerIdVsBodyString=new Map<String,List<Task>>();

  global Database.QueryLocator Start(Database.BatchableContext bc)
  {

      return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT ID,createddate,what.id,Owner.Email,OwnerId,Owner.Name,Status,ActivityDate,Subject from Task WHERE Status != 'Completed' AND Owner.isactive = True  AND ActivityDate!=NULL AND ActivityDate <=:system.today()]);
  }

  global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Task>scope)
  {
      for(Task task:scope)
      {
          String dueDate = task.ActivityDate.format();
          String Subject =task.Subject;
          DateTime dt=task.CreatedDate;
          String what=task.What.Id;
          String status=task.Status;
          htmlBody +='<tr><td>' + what + '</td><td>' + Subject +'</td><td>'+ dt + '</td><td>'+ dueDate +'</td><td>'+ status + '</td></tr>';

          if(!ownerIdVsBodyString.containsKey(task.OwnerId))
          {
              ownerIdVsBodyString.put(task.OwnerId, ownerIdVsBodyString.get(task.Owner.Email)+htmlBody);
          }else{
              ownerIdVsBodyString.put(task.OwnerId,htmlBody);
          }

      }



  }
  global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc)
  {
      // We can send at max 10 emails in a transaction. So we would be using a helper batch to send emails

      Database.executeBatch(new EmailSenderBatch(),10 ); //Scope as 10
  }


  public class email EmailSenderBatch implements Database.Batchable<Sobject>, Database.Stateful{
      Map<String,String> ownerIdVsBodyString=new Map<String,List<Task>>();

      public EmailSenderBatch(Map<String,String> ownerIdVsBodyString){
          this.ownerIdVsBodyString = ownerIdVsBodyString;

      }


      global List<User>  Start(Database.BatchableContext bc)
      {

          return [Select id,UserName,Email from User where id in :ownerIdVsBodyString.keySet()]);


      }

      global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<User>userList){
          List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> pendingTaskEmailAlert = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

          for(User user: userList){
              Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();


              email.setSubject('Details of task due by Today');
              email.setTargetObjectId(user.Id); //This is free Unlimited email day. As sending email to user is free
              String userName=user.UserName;
              String htmlBody= '';

              htmlBody = '<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" align="center" bgcolor="#F7F7F7">'+
              +'<tr>'+
              +'<td style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; font-family:Calibri;line-height: 20px; color: #333;"><br />'+
              +'<br />'+
              +'Dear, '+username+',</td>'+
              +'</tr>'+
              +'<tr>'+
              +'<td style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; font-family:Calibri; line-height: 18px; color: #333;">You have Pending Task</td>'+
              +'</tr>'+
              +'</table>';

              htmlBody +=  '<table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse"><tr><th>Related To</th><th>Subject</th><th>Created Date</th><th> Due Date</th></tr>';

              htmlBody +=ownerIdVsBodyString.get(ownerUserId); //Seting the body
              htmlBody += '</table><br>';
              email.setHtmlBody(htmlBody);
              pendingTaskEmailAlert.add(email);
          }
          Messaging.sendEmail(pendingTaskEmailAlert);


      }
  }
  }
  ```

Source : Batch Stateful :https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm#apex_batch_maintain_state

Number of emails can be sent in a transaction : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm

Unlimited emails sent to user: [Single Email Limitaion](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/197012/single-email-limitaion?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: A second batch is not necessary. Yes, you can only call Messaging.sendEmail 10 times per transaction, but you can send far more than 10 *emails* in a transaction, as long as you send them all at once.

Comment: Thnxx Pranay your code help me a lot to how to deal with that issue.